# Create Azure EventHub Message in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-functions

I'm trying to do some Proof of Concept with EventHub and Azure Functions. I have a Generic Webhook Function in C# that I want to pass a message to my EventHub.

I get stuck on the parameter name given on the "Integrate" tab. If I declare that name among the parameters I have to give it a type. I can't figure out what kind of type though... I've tried:

- String (other functions uses that together with the direction, not applicable with webhooks).
- EventData
- IEnumerable

I can't get it to work. If I don't do this I get the error message:
"Missing binding argument named 'outputEventHubMessage'"

If I give it the wrong type I get the message:
"Error indexing method 'Functions.GenericWebhookCSharp1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind to parameter."

I'm probably a bit lost in documentation or just a bit tired, but I'd appreciate any help here!

/Joakim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely you're just missing the `out` keyword on your parameter. Below is a working WebHook function that declares an `out string message` parameter that is mapped to the EventHub output, and writes an EventHub message via `message = "Test Message"`.

Because async functions can't return out parameters, I made this function synchronous (returning an `object` rather than `Task<object>`). If you want to remain async, rather than use an `out` parameter, you can instead bind to an `IAsyncCollector<string>` parameter. You can then enqueue one or more messages by calling the `AddAsync` method on the collector.

More details on the EventHub binding and the types it supports can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support). Note that the other bindings follow the same general patterns.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static object Run(HttpRequestMessage req, out string message, TraceWriter log)
{
    string jsonContent = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

    log.Info($"Webhook was triggered! Name = {data.first}");

    message = "Test Message";

    var res = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {
        greeting = $"Hello {data.first} {data.last}!"
    });

    return res;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot! I was really wondering abut the asynchronous part and thought I had to work with that. Now I can see my messages coming in to my EventHub and can move on to the next bit in my PoC! Many thanks again.